# What are the paintings shown in the Classicaloid OP?

Tags: classicaloid

In the beginning of [the OP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aE4HmyBc5wE) to *Classicaloid*, three different paintings are shown.

[image: first painting: woman with lute]

[image: second painting: old man with score]

[image: third painting: girl and boy with guitar]

(Due to the speed at which the animation pans through these paintings, the quality of screenshots is somewhat low.) What are these three paintings — who are the artist(s), and what exactly are their titles/subjects?

Comment: The first painting took more work than I expected to work out, so I'm posting this, even though the other two paintings were pretty easy to identify; I also couldn't find any obvious discussion of this when I first ran a search for the paintings on the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first painting is [Carlos Saraceni's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlo_Saraceni) c. 1610 painting [*Saint Cecilia and the Angel*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Carlo_Saraceni_-_Saint_Cecilia_and_the_Angel_-_WGA20829.jpg). [Saint Cecilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Cecilia) is the patron saint of musicians.

[image: Saraceni]

The second painting is Caravaggio's [*Rest on the Flight into Egypt*](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Rest_on_the_Flight_into_Egypt_by_Caravaggio). The flight into Egypt clearly refers to [the event in the Gospels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_into_Egypt) where Joseph flees with his family to Egypt to prevent the death of the child Jesus at the hands of Herod. There's not much reason, as far as I know, to associate it with music per se; the angel and its bowed stringed instrument seem to be the artist's own creation.

[image: Caravaggio]

The final painting is [François Boucher's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Boucher) *The Music Lesson*.

[image: Boucher]